# Communication between a thread and a task waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, messaging

I am in this situation:
many clients can send commands to a controller, and the controller must process each command in order, and send back a response to each client. The clients "awaits" for the response asynchronously.

So, by now, when i receive a command from a client, i enqueue the command in a ConcurrentQueue and run a Task where the client waits for a response asynchronously. The controller has a Thread that is always searching for new commands at the ConcurrentQueue, takes the first, process it and should response to the sender (the client), but here is where i get stuck because i don´t know how to make the controller responds EXACTLY to the client that sent the command (the controller has a queue with many commands but doesn´t know who sent them).

My thinking:
It would be great to send a message from a Thread directly to a Task with the response object. Is it something possible?

My code:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> sendBuffer;

public async Task<IViewAppMessage> sendCommandAsync(byte[] command)
{                              
     sendBuffer.Enqueue(command);

      return await Task.Run<IViewAppMessage>(() =>
      {
            //Pool for a response
      }           
}

/* Method executed within a Timer worker thread */
private void senderPool(object stateInfo)
{
    try
    {
        //Stop timer
        senderTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        //Take command from FIFO
        byte[] commandToSend;
        if(sendBuffer.TryDequeue(out commandToSend))
        {
            //Send command to camera
            cameraSender.Send(commandToSend, commandToSend.Length);                    
            byte[] response = cameraListener.Receive(ref endPoint);

            IViewAppMessage returnMessage = processResponse(response);

            //Notify the response. HOW?????????????  
        }                
    }
    catch 
    {
        //Notify Error
    }
    //In any case, timer restarts
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            //Arrancamos timer
            senderTimer.Change(100, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch 
        { 
            //Fatal error
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I know i could use a BlockingCollection with all the reponses, so when the sender receives a response, it allocate it at the collection, and then the clients polls for a response, but with that approach i should give each client an ID (or something similar) to check for a response with its ID. That could be a solution, but i wonder if is it possible to directly send a message to the task with the response, since i think something similar would be a better approach since it wouldn´t be neccesary to make the clients poll nor assing them not concurrent IDs.

Comment: which  type of client ??

Comment: Any client. It is a library, so it could be referenced by a Windows Form and the client would be the ÜI or by a WCF server and the clients would be the services endpoints...

Comment: When you enqueue the command, can't you wrap it in some object that stores details of the sender?

Comment: Yes, i clould... What kind of details? I though about assinging an ID to each command before enqueuing it and make the client to wait for that ID´s response in a BlockingCollection with all the responses, but i just wonder if there is a better solution to directly send a message with the response to the client.

Comment: Why not just take a callback function pointer - or are these requests sent over the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not just enqueue the item to be sent. Include data that allows the consumer to notify the producer. For example, you could include a `TaskCompletionSource` that is set to completed by the consumer at the appropriate point. The producer can `await TaskCompletionSource.Task`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the queue - classic producer consumer pattern, check the [example in MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This would eliminate the use of timer since `queue.Take()` would block until an item is available in the queue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that helps? AFAIK `BlockingCollection` wraps `ConcurrentQueue` by default.

Comment: @DanielKelley bc.Take() would block until an item is added from another thread

Comment: Ok, but i don´t see how could it help to send a response to the client. Do you mean to use a SendQueue and a ResponseQueue? As i said to @DanielKelley, i would like to know if there is a direct messaging solution, better than making all the clients to pool for a response with its ID at a ResponseQueue.

Comment: @MorgoZ maybe create a queue per client? Or use a 'router' to invoke the appropriate client. Also depends on which communication pattern you want to use. Example patterns: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html